# Simple Excel sum formula yields a string of # signs

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

This seems like a very simple Excel command, but it's just yielding a string of pound signs instead of the sum. Why?

(The error message is "Formula omits adjacent cells", which is deliberate and not the source of the problem. Expanding the column width doesn't help.)

[image]

Excel for Mac v16.25 on macOS Mojave v10.14.5

Comment: Try widening your column

Comment: And make sure the cell is not formatted as a date.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly every time this simply means there are more digits in the value than can fit within the defined size of the cell. Widening the cell will fix this.

Additionally, when the values are too long to fit in the cell, they will still show in the formula bar when you click the cell.

Further, you can click the warning icon to learn more about what is going on in the cell if something else is the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

formulas:
in F16 enter `=TYPE(E16)`, and fill down to F27...
in E30 enter `=SUM(E16:E27)`

The displayed Data:

```
-2      1
-5      1
-1      1
-3      1
-2      1
-2,5    1
-2      1
-4,5    1
-6      1
-1,5    1
-2      1
-2,5    1


-34
```

If there is any other answer than 34 to this, and any other value than 1 in the right column for `=TYPE(ref)`, then there is something wicked in the cells of th eleft column.

Verify that the cells are formatted as either "General" or "Number" and does not contain extraneous spaces, a leading tick `'` or

... the wrong decimal separator: Check how it is set in the locale settings (control panel, or e.g. "System Settings > Language support > /Regional formats\" for Ubuntu)

But I don't understand how the above would display as `#####` - which usually is due to a too narrow column, as others has explained.

**I'm guessing: at least cell E30 (with the sum formula) is formatted as text, as such the content might be too wide for the column ;-).**  (Text usually overflows into the next column though...)